# Why do I have to reset permissions of cache folder after every deploy?

Tags: magento2

I am following the [standard deploy procedure for single machines](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/single-machine-deployment.html) except I am clearing the `static` folder as well as clearing and flushing cache.

I am forced to run `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data var/cache`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the reason this was failing

It was the **cronjob**

I set up the cronjob as another user, when I should have used `www-data`

Like so: `sudo crontab -u www-data -e`

and then added the [Magento 2 cronjobs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Deployment steps:
>
> Log in to your production server as, or switch to, the Magento file
>   system owner.

this is because you run commands as another user, not the owner.
to run it properly you either need to switch user or run command as `php` user:

```
su PHP_USER -s /bin/bash -c "bin/magento setup:upgrade"
```

if you run command like this you will see:

```
[root@admin ~]# whoami
root
[root@admin ~]# su php_user -s /bin/bash -c "whoami"
php_user
```

but before properly `chmod` your files, for example :

```
chown -R php_user:php_user * magento_folder
find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
```

`php_user` the user who owns php process.

Comment: In my case `www-data` runs the web server. But the cache files are created by the `ubuntu` user.